# Let ngspice not to generate .out file

Tags: ngspice

We are using `ngspice` to simulate some circuitry. The command is like this:

```
ngspice < autocode3.sp
```

That would generate the correct result which we need.

But it will also generate a file named 'bsim4v5.out'. Is it possible not to generate this file?

Background:
We are using `ngspice` in a web server. If multiple people simulate the same circuitry, the files `bsim4v5.out` will be generated simultaneously which would lead to failure.

Comment: Have you try ```ngspice < autocode3.sp > /dev/null``` ?

Comment: We need to get the result from stdout.

Comment: How 'bout save the output as text to get the result and avoid conflicts, since ngspice does not seem to have a direct option to disable the creation of the *bsim4v5.out* file.? ```ngspice < autocode3.sp > output.txt```.

Comment: We run ngspice on a web server and we don't use file there. All of the communications are through memory (such as pipe, socket, redis, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Put a `.spiceinit` file on $HOME. The content of the file is:

```
set ngbehavior=hsa
set ng_nomodcheck
```